# How to show column and table comment in JetBrains DataGrip?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

Please help how to display column type and table comments in the database explorer, like on this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To see comments in DataGrip menu navigate to *View* → *Appearance* → *Details in Tree View*, and then select *Show comments instead of details*

[image: Details in Tree View]
[image: Show comments instead of details]

Comment: I'm using it very comfortably because of you
Thank you! :)